# Woocommerce API limits AND ussing less resources

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was reading the documentation at:

http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/

I am trying to figure out the limits for the API for the following methods

- $woocommerce->get products/tags
- $woocommerce->get products/categories
- $woocommerce->get products/categories
- $woocommerce->post products/tags
- $woocommerce->post products/batch

For these methods I want to know how many items I can get or save at once. (Batch save for example I want to save 50 at a time; or for getting products I want to get 50 at a time (per page))

Also I am trying to figure out best practices to use less resources on both consumer of the API and receiver of API. Right now in development I have them both on the same machine and the fan really gets going on my laptop

The majority of work is done in products/batch. I am sending almost 4k items in batches of 50.

Comment: Since some time has passed since your question, did you tried to reach the limit and have some followup results/conclusions? This could be helpful for future visitors of the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I know a service that uses WooCommerce says that **their** API calls are rate-limited by IP to 86400 calls per day (one per second on average).

That is **their** service so implies you can go same or higher for WooCommerce

Source: https://github.com/Paymium/api-documentation#rate-limiting

Comment: I didn't ask question clearly. For the methods above; how many can a send receive? for example. When getting products I get them in chunks of 50 right now. For batch save I save in chunks of 50

Comment: @donohoe Are there any other sources that support WooCommerce having this limit? I couldn't find any information related to API call limit.